# Graph theory: Every vertex belongs to some component of the graph

Tags: graph-theory

I know that intuitively, every vertex of some undirected graph must belong to some component of the graph, since at the very least, every vertex of the graph is connected to itself. But how can this be proven formally?

Comment: Graph theory homework isn't really stackoverflow material ;-)  The answer is an exercise in unwrapping the definition of "connected component of a graph".

Comment: Pure math questions are better asked on math.stackexchange.com.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about mathematics, not programming.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the operator ~ on vertices in a (possibly infinite) graph G, where V1 ~ V2  iff there is a path between V1 and V2 (and allowing that V ~ V).  Then ~ is an equivalence relation on vertices(G), since it is reflexive, symmetric and transitive (you should verify each of these properties).

By the definition of a component, each equivalence class in vertices(G)/~ is associated with exactly one component of G, and contains exactly the vertices of the associated component.  [Equivalence classes form a partition of the sets on which they are defined](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_of_a_set#Partitions_and_equivalence_relations), so that each vertex of G is in at least one equivalence class, and hence in exactly one component.